# Python: Return list of public holidays for a specific country

Tags: python, python-holidays

I am trying a get a list public holidays for a country using the Python [Holidays](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) package. I have tried following the steps on the [Git Repo](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays) and a number of other tutorial websites but I keep getting:

`AttributeError: module 'holidays' has no attribute 'UnitedKingdom'`

I installed the package `pip install holidays`

Then followed this example from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-holidays-library/):

```
from datetime import date 
import holidays 

uk_holidays = holidays.UnitedKingdom() 

for ptr in holidays.UnitedKingdom(years = 2018).items(): 
 print(ptr)
```

I have also tried changing the country to another one specified in the documentation, but It still throws the same AttributeError.

I fairly new to working with python so I am not really sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The exact code you mentioned is working on my machine with the holidays package. Can you verify that holidays was installed correctly? `pip show holidays`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try installing via anaconda? 
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

First create a conda environment (named py37 below, name it how you wish), then perform the installation within the environment and execute the script. There may be some weird thing in your base python installation causing the library to not work.

```
conda create --name py37 python=3.7 
conda activate py37
conda install -c conda-forge holidays
```

After this, run the code just as below. If you're using a text editor, you'll need to open that editor from the environment. Or just run from a python kernel through the command line.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Your code on my machine]

I think you should check if the latest version of pip is install on your machine using `pip -v` if not installed , install it and reinstall the holidays module